# Asp.net core - HTML content to Excel Export

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-core

I would like to convert HTML content to Excel but this code not working

```
[HttpGet("download")]
    public async Task Download()
    {
        try
        {
            string db = "<html>….html design</html>";

            //Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=test.xlsx");
            await Response.WriteAsync(sb);
        }
        catch
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Headers.Clear();
        }
        Response.Clear();
    }
```

The downloaded file can't open

[image]

if i change a extension to `xls` it's working fine but not working on **xlsx**. I want a file in `xlsx`. How to solve this?

Comment: Check the byte count of source file and final file to see if they are the same.  The extension on both source and fnal files must be the same.

Comment: @jdweng - Sorry I didn't get you. Can you explain me more

Comment: What is the extension on original file?  What is extension on final file?

Comment: @jdweng - Both are `xlsx`

Comment: Can you use beyond compare to verify the two files are the same?

Comment: @jdweng - Sorry sir I don't know how to do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205547/discussion-between-chris-hadfield-and-jdweng).

Answer (score 0):

`.xlsx` file is a zip file (a package) containing a number of "parts" (typically UTF-8 or UTF-16 encoded) or XML files. The file extension doesn't recognized HTML content , so you can :

1. Generating HTML content and save it to a file with a `.xls`extension.
2. Start using a specialized library for creating Excel files , for example , [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus)  .